# Button calling macro "The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled"

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm calling a macro with multiple arguments from a button. When clicked, a pop-up stating "The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled" appears. However, macros are indeed on and the macro is in my workbook.
Here are some screenshots:

[image]

'KrakenBookImproved.xlsm!DoSingleMarketOrder Evaluate("Folio!$A2"), "USD", Evaluate("Folio!$P$2")'
Is exactly what is assigned to the button

[image]

Here is the macro code and location

[image: Popup]
Here is the popup when I click the button

I'm assuming my macro call

'KrakenBookImproved.xlsm!DoSingleMarketOrder Evaluate("Folio!$A2"), "USD", Evaluate("Folio!$P$2")'

is syntactically incorrect. What is wrong with it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Move the file name and the exclamation mark out of the single quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'KrakenBookImproved.xlsm'!'DoSingleMarketOrder Evaluate("Folio!$A2"), "USD", Evaluate("Folio!$P$2")' Gives the intended behavior

@GSerg 's comment helped. The issue is I need separate sets of apostrophes around the filename and the sub-call.